# How to set password of access database after taking backup

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, c#-2.0

how to set password on access database after taking a backup in c#.so that client can't open the database.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Or you mean another thing?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/8c513514-a588-4ef3-955b-9ea641070bb1